# Find the difference between two strings based on individual words

Tags: javascript

I want to find the difference between two strings. So far I can only return the differences based on characters:

```js
// Given two strings
let speechA = 'you are and you could';
let speechB = "you are and you couldn't"; 

// I want a logic like difference = speechB - speechA
let difference = speechB.replace(speechA, '');

console.log(difference)
```

The desired result should be: **couldn't** not **n't**.

In other words, I want to find the difference based on individual **words** not **characters**.

How can I do that?

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: just split the string by word / whitespace and compare array elements

Comment: btw, what should happen if no word match? what if one match, but is at the wrong position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare the sentences word by word and return what's different in sentence B compared to sentence A at that same position, you may split strings into arrays of words and compare those:

```js
const speechA = `you are and you could`,
      speechB = `you are and you couldn't`

const getStrDifference = (s1, s2) => {
  const a1 = s1.split(' '),
        a2 = s2.split(' ')
  return a2.reduce((diff, word, pos) => (word != a1[pos] && diff.push(word), diff), [])
}

console.log(getStrDifference(speechA, speechB))
```

Comment: @foxer : Perfect choice ;) Aside from considering word order and quantity, above algorithm is [faster](https://jsbench.me/jak7exat5l/1) compared to `.filter()`-based, which are of O(n²) time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Just split your strings with the withspace and create arrays. Then compare the arrays.
Take a look at following:

```js
// Given two strings
let speechA = 'you are and you could';
let speechB = "you are and you couldn't"; 

// I want a logic like difference = speechB - speechA
let difference =diffOfArrays(speechB.split(' '), speechA.split(' '));


function diffOfArrays(A, B) {
    return A.filter(function (a) {
        return B.indexOf(a) == -1;
    });
}

console.log(difference)
```

Answer (score 2):

This example returns an array of words that are in `string1`and not in `string2`

```js
const string1 = "hello i am dave gibbs friend";
const string2 = "hello i am mike gibbs buddy";

const string1Arr = string1.split(" ");
const string2Arr = string2.split(" ");

const diffWords = string1Arr.filter( word => {

  return !string2Arr.includes(word);

})

console.log(diffWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```js
// Given two strings
let speechA = 'you are and you could';
let speechB = "you are and you couldn't"; 

// I want a logic like difference = speechB - speechA
var temp = speechA.split(' ');
let difference = speechB.split(' ').filter(w => !temp.includes(w)).join(', ');

console.log(difference)
```